# How do Teamcity artifact paths work?

Tags: visual-studio, teamcity, artifact

Can anyone give me an example of what the Artifact paths setting defined for a build configuration could look like if I want to create two artifacts dist and source where I am using the sln 2008 build runner and building my projects using the default bin/Release?

```
**/Source/Code/MyProject/bin/Release/*.* => dist
**/*.* => source
```

I get two artifact roots dist and source but under dist I get the whole directory structure (Source/Code/MyProject/bin/Release) which I don't want and under source I get the whole thing along with obj and bin/Release which I do not want.

Can you give some advice on how to do this correctly?

Do I need to change the target location for all the projects I am building to be able to get this thing to work?

Answer (score 28):

So you'll just need:

```
Source\Code\MyProject\bin\Release\* => dist
Source\**\* => source
```

This will put all the files in release into a artifact folder called dist and everything in Source into a artifact folder called source.

If you have subfolders in Release try:

```
Source\Code\MyProject\bin\Release\**\* => dist
```

Comment: what happens if your path has a space in it?  I've tried path in quotes and using "\ " and neither seems to work....

Comment: How could I use that artifact folder in a dependency?
e.g.: B -> A.
I set A's artifacts paths in dependencies as "target-directory\**\* => ."
I set B's artifacts paths in general settings as "**/* => target_directory"
Is it right?
Thanks

Comment: The reason that the full path is brought over is because the source path has a wildcard in the path (the `**` at the start). You either need to define the path in full like in this answer or use params to pass it through.

Answer (score 0):

According to TeamCity documentation; it should be like this:

```
file_name|directory_name|Ant-like wildcard [ => target_directory ]
```

So..

```
Source\Code\MyProject\bin\Release|**\* => dist  (| not \)
```

Comment: Three years later, I guess not.

Comment: '|' indicates "one of", or "or", so this means "File name" or "directory name" or "ant-like wildcard". The pipe should not be treated literally.